# Upgrading nginx-full 1.2.1 to nginx 1.2.6 from PPA on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, apt, dpkg

I'm trying to upgrade nginx 1.2.1 to version 1.2.6 on ubuntu 12.10, but with no luck. I've previously installed nginx using `apt-get install nginx-full` because I needed the modules instead of building from sources. 
But now I can't 'overwrite' the old package with the apt-get from below

```
$ apt-get install nginx
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nginx
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 415 kB of archives.
After this operation, 930 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ quantal/nginx nginx amd64 1.2.6-1~quantal [415 kB]
Fetched 415 kB in 2s (186 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package nginx.
(Reading database ... 77029 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking nginx (from .../nginx_1.2.6-1~quantal_amd64.deb) ...
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Thanks for using NGINX!

Check out our community web site:
* http://nginx.org/en/support.html

If you have questions about commercial support for NGINX please visit:
* http://www.nginx.com/support.html

----------------------------------------------------------------------
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx_1.2.6-1~quantal_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/sbin/nginx', which is also in package nginx-full 1.2.1-2.2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/nginx_1.2.6-1~quantal_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I don't want to mess with all the configured websites I have in nginx, is there a safe upgrade method in this case? I need realip_module, upstream_module, rewrite_module, memcached_module, headers_module, fastcgi_module but I don't know the the package 'nginx' from the PPA has all the modules within the package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer from http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/fix-dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-x.html

> Fixing this (in most cases but probably not all) is quite simple: look for path of the  file that caused the error - in my first example that would be "/var/cache/apt/archives/smplayer_0.6.9+svn3595-1ppa1~maverick1_i386.deb", an run the following command:
>
> `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/smplayer_0.6.9+svn3595-1ppa1~maverick1_i386.deb`
>
> If "--force-overwrite" doesn't work, you can try "--force-all" instead.
>
> In the above command, replace "/var..." with the exact path to the .deb that caused the error on your computer. If you've installed it from a repository, the .deb is located in /var/cache/apt/archives but if not, it's wherever you've downloaded it (either way, the error should display its exact path so you don't have to look for it manually).
>
> What the above command does is force the overwrite of the file that exists in 2 packages and caused the error. Then, to make sure all the packages have installed successfully, also run the following command:
>
> `sudo apt-get install -f`